# Как работать с md5

Tags: php

Я хочу сделать защищённый пароль с md5. Я сделал шифрование на нём: md5($password). В базе данных пароль сохраняется по типу 7692f4у61. Как мне сделать, чтобы когда пользователь ввёл свой пароль он заходил, ибо выдает, что пароль не верен, тк представлен в другом виде?

Я, скорее всего, не понимаю принципа его работы, в интернете ничего не нашел. Помогите разобраться с md5, как его использовать?

Comment: надо сделать md5 от введенного пользователем пароля и сравнивать уже это с БД

Comment: @Mike немного не понял. Это как? Можно поподробнее? Я понимаю часть вещей, но не так сильно продвинут. Не понимаю фразы "сделать md5 от введенного пользователем пароля". И как сравнивать?

Comment: Не используйте md5 вообще нигде, особенно в паролях. Он давным-давно устарел, а для паролей вообще никогда не был безопасным. У php есть специальные функции для паролей http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-hash.php

Comment: @andreymal а как сделать, чтобы при введении пользователем пароля он мог зайти? В БД пароль же будет в виде ваоыощапр2ц9ре..

Comment: @ЛёшаВолосников переводите введённый пользователем пароль в такой же вид ваоыощапр2ц9ре и сравнивайте со значением из базы. И вообще читайте документацию по приведённой мной ссылке

Comment: И по этой ссылке тоже http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-verify.php

Comment: @andreymal Кажется я начинаю понимать как это работает. Спасибо

Comment: @andreymal за поправку с md5 тоже. Буду иметь ввиду

Comment: Собранное в одном месте - http://php.net/manual/ru/faq.passwords.php